# docker compose not exposing ports

Tags: docker-compose

I have a dockerfile that works by itself, with

> docker build -t image_apache .
> docker run -tid -p 5000:80 --name=container_apache image_apache

This works, and I can connect to its webserver with 127.0.0.1:5000

But when I try to create a docker-compose.yml file to build and run the image with docker-compose, it doesn't appear to expose the port at all.

Here is the docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'

services:
  deploy_test:
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    build: .
    working_dir: /tmp/artifacts
```

> docker-compose build
> docker-compose run deploy_test

My browser can't connect to 127.0.0.1:8080, and the apache log in the container doesn't show any attempts.

Do I just have a bad syntax for the port? It matches online samples.

Comment: Hi, I think issue is with using `docker-compose run` command. Please check its documentation for ports. Also, as an alternate, you can try `docker-compose up -f test.yaml`. Then try connecting to your port.

Comment: Thanks. Adding the same port options on the command line worked. It seems weird to have the port options in the yaml and the command line.

Comment: Yes, it's weird, but as I said, to overcome it, you can use `up` command instead of `run`.

Comment: up isn't working for me, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Do you want to post an answer adding -p 8080:80 to the docker-compose command line, and maybe link https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/ ?

Comment: Hi, yes I'd post it as answer but I can't seem to figure out why is `up` not exposing ports in your case. I will let you know if I find anything regarding that. Also, you can try listing all running containers with details using `ps` command. Maybe, that way we can know if service is opening up containers ports or if host has any issue.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting for posting an answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

please try using `docker-compose run -p 8080:80 deploy_test` as `run` command can not expose/publish ports by itself i.e. you need to specify it manually. For more information regarding same, please refer to its official documentation [here](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/).